# How to calculate signed and unsigned Gradient orientations in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, feature-descriptor

When calculating the gradient orientation for using it in HOG descriptor extraction,  we can either choose to use gradient orientations between 0-180 or 0-360, how can we produce such angles using Matlab? i have the following code:

```
Im=imread('cameraman.tif'); // reading the image
Im=double(Im);  // converting it to double
hx = [-1,0,1];  // the gradient kernel for x direction
hy = -hx;      // the gradient kernel for y direction
grad_x = imfilter(Im,hx);   //gradient image in x direction
grad_y = imfilter(Im,hy);   // gradient image in y direction

% angles in 0-180:
...
%angles in 0-360:
...
```

Comment: You can also use the `extractHOGFeatures` function in the Computer Vision System Toolbox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually you can use [`atan2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/atan2.html) to generate angles that are between -180 and 180 given your horizontal and vertical gradient components, and hence **signed** angles.  However, if you want angles from 0 to 360 or **unsigned** angles, all you have to do is search for any angles that are generated by `atan2` that are negative, and add 360 to each angle.  This will allow you to get the angle between `[0,360)`.  For example, an angle of -5 degrees is actually 355 degrees unsigned.  Therefore:

```
angles = atan2(grad_y, grad_x); %// Signed
angles(angles < 0) = 2*pi + angles(angles < 0); %// Unsigned
```

Here `atan2` is in **radians**, so we add `2*pi` instead of 360 degrees.  If you'd like degrees instead of radians, use the equivalent degrees call: [`atan2d`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/atan2d.html) and therefore:

```
angles = atan2d(grad_y, grad_x); %// Signed
angles(angles < 0) = 360 + angles(angles < 0); %// Unsigned
```

---

Going with your comments, you would also like to do the reverse.  Basically, if we are given an unsigned angle, how do we go to a signed angle?  Simply do the opposite.  Find all angles that are `> 180`, then take this angle and subtract by 360.  For example, an angle of 182 unsigned is -178 signed, or 182 - 360 = -178.

Therefore:

## Radians

```
angles(angles > pi) = angles(angles > pi) - (2*pi);
```

## Degrees

```
angles(angles > 180) = angles(angles > 180) - 360;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast answer, i want to ask what if i want to map the angles fro 0-360 to 0-180?

Comment: @Apastrix - That is simply the opposite :) Search for any angles that are `> 180` then subtract by 360 degrees.

Comment: @Apastrix - I've updated my post to do the opposite.  Have a look.

Comment: I'm very embarrassed to ask you this after your double help, but in my comment i didn't want the reverse, i want to start from angles of 0-360 and go to angles of 0-180, so i need a mapping where 0 remains 0 and 360 becomes 180.

Comment: If you go to 0-180 from 0-360, you're disregarding the angles that form the lower half of the Cartesian space.  What happens for angles that are between 181 to 360 (non-inclusive)?  How do those get mapped?

Comment: @rayryend Ok i got you, i think the mapping in this situation doesn't work, i appreciate you help!

Comment: No problem at all.  If you do have any further questions, just ping me here.  Good luck!

Comment: @rayryeng what happens if you want to map the signed gradients from -180/180 to 0 - 180 (half binning). How would the negative gradients would be mapped to the positives?

Comment: @Pepelee start with a simple case. An angle of -5 degrees maps to 175 degrees for half binning. The ray that this angle makes on the Cartesian plane extends to 175 degrees on the positive side of the y = 0 plane. Similarly, an angle of -80 degrees is 100 degrees. Therefore by this logic, in general simply add 180 degrees to any angles that are negative instead of 360.